# insert value next other columns

Tags: mysql

I need to add values into a column. The problem here is that i need to insert it beside a column. When i run an insert query,

```
INSERT INTO `livemigrationauditingdb`.`system_audit` (
                        `Comp`
                        )
                        VALUES (
                        'standard1'
                        )");
```

it displays:

```
---------+---------+
         |standard1|
---------+---------+
  default|         |
---------+---------+
  default|         |
---------+---------+
```

i want it to hopefully display:

```
---------+---------+
 default |standard1|
---------+---------+
 default |         |
---------+---------+
```

any ideas guys?

Comment: How do you identify which row to add the value on?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is not an insert, but an update to an existing row.

Assuming your table has some kind of `id` column to identify the respective row, you can use an `UPDATE` statement ([MySQL docu](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)):

```
UPDATE `livemigrationauditingdb`.`system_audit` SET `Comp`='standard1' WHERE `id`='identifyingValue';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `INSERT` so it is inserting in the next row. Instead you should use `UPDATE` command.

Assuming that you want to  set it beside a particular value in the adjacent column, say `xxx` in column `yyy`. So you can do it like this:

```
UPDATE `livemigrationauditingdb`.`system_audit`
SET  `Comp` = 'standard1'
WHERE `yyy` = `xxx`;
```